# How to disable the logging completely for a DAG in airflow?

Tags: python-2.7, airflow

I have a dag file in which I have defined the DAG and its tasks. I want to disable the logging only for this DAG. Any idea how to do that? I don't' want to modify airflow.cfg or any other file except the file which has the definition of the current DAG.

Comment: Do you want to disable the log/output of each task within the DAG or the log for the whole DAG itself, including logs from the Scheduler (when it`s generating the DagBag)?

Comment: @dorvak Specifically, I want to disable the logs of the whole dag, doesn't care about the scheduler logs.

Comment: To my knowledege, there is no (or no feasible) way to do that from within the DAG definition file. You can can of course disable the logging for each Operator or the DAG-Object (f.e. overriding their _log/log/logging-methods), but the base_task_runner and other components will still produce a log (when the pick up the DAG etc.). You woud need to override all of these classes within your DAG definition file. It`s probably easier to clean your log files/database from within the DAG itself by using PythonOperators that perform these jobs at the end of the DAG.